# Carpeta 'bin' en MySQL para recuperar contraseña

Tags: mysql

estoy tratando de recuperar la contraseña de MySQL pero cuando busco la carpeta 'bin' dentro de la carpeta MySQL no aparece. para seguir el paso a paso necesito esa carpeta pero no la encuentro.

Comment: Y no crees que para ayudarte necesitamos más datos?? Respuesta Fácil: **Entonces crea la carpeta**.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!